# Double vertical scrollbars are showing on iFrame page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an index page that includes both a left and a right iFrame. For some reason on the second iFrame it shows a scroll bar for its iFrame and another scroll bar for the whole page.

I have been trying to remove the scroll bar for the whole page and just leave the scroll bars for the 2 iFrames only

When I go and change the css property to overflow hidden for the body,html element it also removes the scroll bar for both iFrams

I have even tried to set the iFrame element overflow-y: to auto and the body,html overflow to hidden.

That still didn't work.

The second issue I am having is that the iFrame does not extend all the way to the bottom of the page even when I specified the height to be a 100% .

I have been fiddling with the CSS but go no luck so far. I would appreciate it if anyone can try to help me out.

Below is the link to my webpage, and the css snippet. Thank you!!!

```
html,body{ height: 100%; margin:0;padding:0; }
iframe{
    height:100%; margin:0;padding:0; border: 0;
}
```

http://15c04752.ngrok.com/simplemenu/menus/demo (Text might be rendered smaller in different browsers please hit ctrl+ cmd+ on your keyboard to get the scrolling to show)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the scrollbar for the whole page, add this rule:

```
    body, html {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

To enable scrollbars on the iframes, add this attribute:

```
<iframe ... scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp)

And that's how it looks like, if you add both:

[image]

There is no scrollbar for the whole page, no scrollbar for the left iframe (because the content is fully visible) and a scrollbar for the right iframe (because the content is not fully visible). If you make the windows smaller, the scrollbar for the left iframe will appear.

Comment: Hey Darek. That is not didn't help because my iFrame scroll bars disappear.

Comment: The only visible scrollbar without my rule added is the scrollbar of the whole page. I cannot see any frame scrollbar, neither with Chrome nor with IE11. If you want to add a scrollbar to the iframe, you need to add this attribute (to the iframe, not css): `scrolling="yes"`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: But I am trying to remove the scrolling of the whole page and just keep the scrolling for iFrame only. If i set the attribute to scrolling="yes" and keep overflow:hidden on the body and HTML, the iFrame scrolling still doesn't appear.

Comment: You've updated your page, and I can see the iframe scrollbars, if the height is bigger than their contents. I can also see the scrollbar for the whole page again, because you altered your css style and added `scrolling` to `overflow`, which is invalid.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying. I have added scrolling.. but there is no overflow property ...

Comment: It also says the scrolling feature is not supported in HTML5... so what is the point of adding it?

Comment: You've removed the `overflow: hidden` part again... I've added a screenshot using both rules, and it works exactly as you want it (tested using Chrome and IE). You might want to try `iframe {overflow: scroll;}` instead, but `scrolling="yes"` definitely works.

Comment: Hey Derek. Thanks for the response. I did figure out the problem. The left and right frame and index.php page where all sharing one style. So when I set the overflow to hidden the iFrame  body of the 2 iframes where also hidden. What I did is just set overflow to hidden on the index page only

Also there is reason to add scrolling="yes" as an attribute since HTML5 does not support it anymore

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should upvote and/or mark this answer as correct, otherwise it will still appear under "unsolved questions". If you come up with your own solution, you should post it and mark it as solved instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using an iframe. The element containing the iframe was not long enough to justify a second scrollbar; its just a youtube video taking up about 600 pixels in height so I did not need a second scrollbar. The fix for me was just
`html, body { height: 100%; }`
in CSS. If that doesn't help my next best guess is to use webkit to just visibly hide them if all else fails.